# Does my ecommerce site NEED sha-256 for SagePay?

Tags: ssl, opayo

I've had an email from Sagepay: "Reminder of security certificate update" it says: *you’ll need to ensure that your Sage Pay integration is capable of working with the SHA-256 algorithm and support for SHA-1 will be disabled when we switch*.

Reading about SHA256 I get this: *In order to get a SHA-2 certificate, you have to first pick an SSL provider who is capable of supplying certificates signed by SHA-2. We have researched the market and documented major brands who are signing certificates with SHA-2. These brands are Symantec, GeoTrust, Thawte, RapidSSL and Comodo.* which implies that it relates to web sites using https.

My site doesn't have a secure certificate and I thought that one reason to use a PSP like SagePay was so that I could pass customers to SagePay's secure system to handle payment information.  I don't keep any customer or order details on the server.

Have I misunderstood?

BTW PHPinfo says Hashing Engines:md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256... etc is this relevant

Comment: If your site is not itself fully HTTPS, a man-in-the-middle can rewrite your link to SagePay to point to their malicious server, which pretends to be SagePay just long enough to steal your customers' money.

Comment: Having said that, that's *probably* not what SagePay is warning you about.  It sounds to me more like there is code you run on your site that needs to be able to verify *SagePay*'s SSL certificates.

Comment: I would recommend you discuss this with SagePay's customer support.

Comment: What type of SagePay integration are you using? I'm assuming it's forms?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.Its a perl script , part of ecommerce product "Sellerdeck" it just sends amount and customer name to Sagepay.  Sagepay opens in a secure browser window and takes card details, and Sagepay sends back (to PERL) transaction result (i.e. yes or no).